# Code editor for mac with specific shortcuts

Tags: osx, text-editor, ide

I need a free code editor for MacOS.
I'm currently using Komodo Edit 10, which is the closest to what I need but it crashes too much to be used seriously.

Here's what I'd like :

- Light (not a full IDE, I don't care about FTP support etc... just want fast loading)
- Support of common webdev languages (PHP, JS, html/css...)
- Basic autocompletion
- Emmet support
- A view of ALL methods and properties if the file is a PHP or JS class (currently using NST plugin for komodo : exactly what I need but now dead and buggy)
- Smart shortcuts and custom shortcuts. The editor with the best shortcuts management to me is notepad++ for windows. I'd mostly like the following :

  - Line / Block commenting/uncommenting with the SAME shortcut. Editors often use a different shortcut to comment a selection or just a line and this is just stupid.
  - Line swapping. I didn't think it would be so hard to find a simple line swap to invert a line with the line before. Without moving the custor, obviously
  - A fast EMMET selector expansion. Emmets plugins for komodo are ridiculous, it's faster to type everything myself than to wait for it to expand a simple selector...

I thinks that's all.

I tried a lot of editors and I can't find this class view thing !

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Atom or Sublime text? Atom is free and Sublime has a free trial that appears to be endless. Both are very configurable and are can be used for many different computer languages. A web development specific app, Brackets by Adobe is free and very nice. I use it myself.  All 3 apps mentioned have plugins or extensions for different enhancements. Brackets is free.

Another code editor app I tested recently is Visual Studio Code. It too is free. The more traditional type editors, Text Wrangler, Emacs and Vim are free options. Emacs and Vim have a long learning curve and are keyboard focused as opposed to using a mouse. There is a large community of users for both emacs and Vim. The users of these two are adamant about their editors. Both are highly customizable.

Comment: I tested all 3, but didn't like them at the time. Maybe bracket was too new, i'll give it another chance. I think i didn't find a way to get the class view. I hate sublime text, except for SQL and large files, I dont know I just hate it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Geany - Free/Open, available for Linux/OS X/Windows, same syntax highlighting as Notepad++, configurable custom keyboard shortcuts, multiple files, terminal window, can tie to your compiler/etc and actually build from within the editor.

In fact, it is more of a super light weight IDE than a plain text editor.

But I think it rocks.

Comment: Well I NEVER heard of this one ! Testing it right now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

**CudaText** editor is suitable, it is free/ open source.
Items which mentioned, almost all present.

- Basic auto-completion is done for HTML/CSS, while for other syntaxes a plugin needed (exists for: JS, and Python).
- Emmet: plugin works, but with NodeJS installed (must install Node on Mac).
- Shortcuts: are configurable via F1, then F9.
- View of all methods: present via Code Tree panel on left.

[image: Css completions]